# Pyautogui copy dynamic data shown after id filling in search field of the website

Tags: python, bots, tracking, pyautogui

I am willing to create bot using pyautogui to open new tab for the specific website and write ID in search field, until this is done.

based on the ID data will shown, **how can i copy or extract the data shown as the data dynamic for different ID?**

Comment: Since it seems you need to automatize HTTP calls, have you considered `requests` or even `selenium` instead of `pyautogui`?